# SOLR dataimport 404 Error

Tags: solrnet, solr, dataimporthandler

I m facing Problem with **Dataimport** in Solr. if i call this Link

**http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false**

showing Error

HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /solr/dataimport. Reason:

```
NOT_FOUND
```

I have follow Same as per Solr suggestion with this link

**http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler**

My Configuration Looks like:-

**1.** in **solrconfig.xml**

```
< requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    < lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml< /str>
    < /lst>
  < /requestHandler>
```

**2.** in **data-config.xml** (its in same folder of solrconfig.xml)

```
< dataConfig>
  < dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
        driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        url="jdbc:127.0.0.1;databaseName=testsolr"
        user="testsolr"
        password="12345678"/>
  < document name="Product">
    < entity name="Item_ID" query="select Item_ID from item">      
     < /entity>
  < /document>
< /dataConfig>
```

**3.** in **Lib folder** (donwloaded the Microsoft JDBC SQL Connector)

I have putted "sqljdbc4.jar" file in Lib folder

after that i started the solr but still i m getting Same error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Check whether you are recieving "Welcome to solr" page on entering

`"http://localhost:8080/solr/"` on bowser.

If it is not having any issue means try with this query..

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false
```

In case if you are using multicore add it to your query,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/**yourcore**/admin/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false
```

Comment: I am still researching into solr with multiple cores. In my case the url is http://localhost:8983/solr//**yourcore**/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false
. I don't have "admin" in the url after the core name.

Comment: I got the solution Thanks for your valuable time. even i developed an Ecom website using Solr visit: http://www.otherlandtoys.co.uk/

Comment: could you update the Question with the solution , i got the same problems and all the answers here didn't work with me

Answer (score 2):

In principle, your link should work.

404 could mean, that the server host and port is correct.
This error occurs, if the instance name is not correct.
Maybe your instance-name is testsolr, so your url should be:

http://localhost:8983/testsolr/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false

//Edit: you will find your instance-name here: `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps`

Comment: Thanks for your Response. 
I checked the instance Name, its correct. but still same Error.

Comment: Could you please check, how many solr instances are running (ps -efa | grep tomcat). Maybe there is an 2nd instance, running on an different port?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting solr. The solrconfig.xml file needs to reload so that the /dataimport path is available.

Comment: restarting solr doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I, without understanding the ramifications, changed the config in solrconfig.xml for the DataImportHandler requestHandler, it 'moved' my Data Import url to /sfdcorgs rather than the default of /dataimport and I got a 404:

```
<requestHandler name="/sfdcorgs" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">/Users/sherod/data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case too I was getting 404 error, I clean up the index before starting indexing by:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true
```

Problem got solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to access to dataimport.jsp to solve my 404.